# Fitting two trees on the same page

Tags: align

How do I put these two trees on the same page?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{forest}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}

    \textit{Generator $(12)$}
\[\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=8em,s sep=3em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(12)$}
 [,label=above:{$()$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}
  [,label=right:$(12)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(12)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=7em,s sep=4em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above:{$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\]

\textit{Generator $(13)$}
\[\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=8em,s sep=3em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(13)$}
 [,label=above:{$(132)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$()$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}
  [,label=right:$(12)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=7em,s sep=4em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above:{$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\]    
\end{landscape}
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is the following:

- reduce spaces in matrices with

```
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
```

- reduce `s sep` distance from `4em` to `3em`
- reduce space between trees titles and trees, for example

```
    \textit{Generator $(13)$}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
```

Considering above I got the following result:

[image]

Complete MWE, which gives above result is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
    \textit{Generator $(12)$}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\[\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree = {grow'=east,
            l sep=7em,
            s sep=3em,
            circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,
            }
[,label=left:{$(12)$}
 [,label=above:{$()$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}
  [,label=right:$(12)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(12)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree = {grow'=east,
            l sep=7em,
            s sep=3em,
            circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,
            font=\small}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above:{$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\]

    \textit{Generator $(13)$}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
\[\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree = {grow'=east,
            l sep=7em,
            s sep=3em,
            circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,
            font=\small}
[,label=left:{$(13)$}
 [,label=above:{$(132)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$()$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}
  [,label=right:$(12)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(13)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree = {grow'=east,
            l sep=7em,
            s sep=3em,
            circle,inner sep=2pt,fill,
            font=\small}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above:{$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\]
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the neat solution!